# web service deployed in glass fish cannot be accessed from internet but only locally

Tags: web-services, glassfish

I deployed a webservice on glassfish and i can access it within the server (locally). But cannot call the service through internet. The server is an amazon server. it has an elastic ip as well.
Please explain me how to configure it so that i can access the service from internet.
Thank you.